# make UIImage fill the entire navigationBar

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

I want to insert an image inside a ui navigation bar and make it look as an aspect fit image looks inside an imageView.
i am doing it as

```
navigationController?.navigationBar.compactAppearance?.backgroundImageContentMode = .scaleToFill
        navigationController?.navigationBar.setBackgroundImage(image, for: .default)
```

But it is giving me the output as :

[image]

How can i make it perfect.

Comment: can you share your image ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simplest way to use the `UIImageView` here with `scaleAspectFit` image property. Try the following working code block.

```
func setNavigation() {
    let imageView = UIImageView(image: UIImage(named: "bankselected"))
    imageView.frame = navigationController!.navigationBar.frame
    imageView.backgroundColor = .lightGray
    imageView.contentMode = .scaleAspectFit
    navigationController?.navigationBar.addSubview(imageView)
  }
```

> [image]

Comment: i want that house icon to fill the entire navigationBar below time and network indicators.

Comment: @RattanKumar: Try with `.scaleToFill` property!!

Answer (score 0):

You can use this Protocol to add image in your navigationBar

```
protocol CustomizableNavigationBar {
    var navigationBar: UINavigationBar? { get }
}

extension CustomizableNavigationBar {
    func setNavBarLogo() {

        let imageView = UIImageView(image: UIImage(named: "artistAvatar1"))
        imageView.frame = navigationBar!.frame
        imageView.contentMode = .scaleToFill
        navigationBar?.addSubview(imageView)
    }
}
```

Use it like This

```
class SearchViewController: UIViewController,CustomizableNavigationBar {

     var navigationBar: UINavigationBar?

     override func viewDidLoad() {
            super.viewDidLoad()
            navigationBar = navigationController?.navigationBar
            setNavBarLogo()

        }
}
```

[image]